# Cannot change service name when the service is running

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to start my service but I get the followig error:

> Service cannot be started. System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot
>   change service name when the service is running.    at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.set_ServiceName(String value)    at
>   Bar.Bar.InitializeComponent() in
>   \workgroup.net
>   projects\Bar\Bar\Bar.Designer.vb:line 47    at
>   Bar.Bar.OnStart(String[] args) in
>   \workgroup.net
>   projects\Bar\Bar\Bar.vb:line 22    at
>   System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.ServiceQueuedMainCallback(Object
>   state

I'm not trying to change the service name at all !!!  what can causes the error?

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
    InitializeComponent()
    writeToLog("in onstart")
    folderToWatch = New FileSystemWatcher
    folderToWatch.Path = sDocDir
    With folderToWatch
        .NotifyFilter = .NotifyFilter Or NotifyFilters.FileName
        .NotifyFilter = .NotifyFilter Or NotifyFilters.Attributes
    End With
    AddHandler folderToWatch.Created, AddressOf ProcessBarCode
    folderToWatch.EnableRaisingEvents = True
End Sub
```

The `InitializeComponent` function:

```
'Required by the Component Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

' NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Component Designer
' It can be modified using the Component Designer.  
' Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    'Bar'
    Me.ServiceName = "Bar"

End Sub
```

Comment: It is telling you in the stack trace.. `Me.ServiceName = "Bar"` is the issue

Comment: @AFriend Thank you but it's on the designer I can't delete this line, as the note indicates: Do not modify it using the code editor.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but if you override the initialisation components, shouldn't you call `Base.OnStart`  before your own code? This might also include a call to `InitialiseComponent` and the events will fire in the right sequence.

Comment: @AJD It worked till a few days ago, and you don't have to call `Base.OnStart` on a service.

Comment: @user3378165: "It worked till a few days ago ...". Don't you think that this bit of information was important? What has changed over the last few days?

Comment: @AJD That's what I am wondering, the code wasn't changed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The InitializeComponent() method call is placed incorrectly.  Hard to get wrong when you use the Windows Service project template, the auto-generated code in the Service1.cs source file looks like this:

```
    public Service1() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

In other words, the service gets its name when the constructor runs.  Which happens very early, the auto-generated code in Program.cs looks like:

```
    static void Main() {
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
        {
            new Service1()                    // <=== here
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
    }
```

In other words, immediately at startup of the program, before it starts to interact with the OS and has committed to the service name.  OnStart() is far too late, it is a callback from the OS.

So verify that the constructor and Main() entrypoint still look good.  And delete the call from OnStart().

Comment: Thank you very much for the well explained answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up commented out this line in the designer and that solved the issue:

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    'Me.ServiceName = "Bar"
End Sub
```